# How to implement GPSR algorithm in ns3 ?

Tags: routes, ns-3

I want to implement gpsr using  ns3 .For this purpose , I am follwing [this github project.](https://github.com/nandanwarchetan/ns3-gpsr) In this project ,  I am reading readme file . I have found that I have to execute this command : "./waf configure;./waf" .

So I enter in my terminal my folder path.When i put `./waf configure` , it has showed me configuration is successfull.Then I put `./waf` it show this type of error .

```
../src/core/model/unix-system-wall-clock-ms.cc: In member function ‘int64_t ns3::SystemWallClockMsPrivate::End()’:
../src/core/model/unix-system-wall-clock-ms.cc:78:44: error: ‘_SC_CLK_TCK’ was not declared in this scope
   static int64_t ticksPerSecond = sysconf (_SC_CLK_TCK);
                                            ^
../src/core/model/unix-system-wall-clock-ms.cc:78:55: error: ‘sysconf’ was not declared in this scope
   static int64_t ticksPerSecond = sysconf (_SC_CLK_TCK);
```

It also shows me the reason to get this error :

```
Build failed
 -> task failed (exit status 1): 
    {task 139770074846736: cxx unix-system-wall-clock-ms.cc -> unix-system-wall-clock-ms.cc.1.o}
['/usr/bin/g++', '-O0', '-ggdb', '-g3', '-Wall', '-Werror', '-Wno-error=deprecated-declarations', '-fstrict-aliasing', '-Wstrict-aliasing', '-fPIC', '-pthread', '-Ibuild', '-I.', '-DNS3_ASSERT_ENABLE', '-DNS3_LOG_ENABLE', '-DSQLITE3=1', '-DHAVE_IF_TUN_H=1', '-DPYTHONDIR="/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"', '-DPYTHONARCHDIR="/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"', '-DHAVE_PYTHON_H=1', '-DENABLE_GSL', '../src/core/model/unix-system-wall-clock-ms.cc', '-c', '-o', 'src/core/model/unix-system-wall-clock-ms.cc.1.o']
```

So can you suggest me an way to resolve this error ? Why am I getting this error ? What can I do to run GPSR algorithm in ns3 ? I badly need the simulation of GPSR algorithm . Thanks for your co-operation .

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this include to src/core/model/unix-system-wall-clock-ms.cc

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

Some systems (such as yours) need this explicitly added while others may pull it in with another header file.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion seems it works. But the follwing error exist   https://paste.ubuntu.com/26323905/
                                                         ^

Comment: Note, I suggest that you consider to use ns-3-users Google Group for future ns-3 questions of this type.  There have been other discussions in that forum about using GPSR for ns-3.